# Active class not being added when alias is used

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have below my routes

```
import Cart from './Cart.vue'
import ProductList from './ProductList.vue'
import ViewProduct from './ViewProduct.vue'

export const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'index',
        component: ProductList,
    },
    {
        path: '/cart',
        name: 'cart',
        alias: '/shopping-cart',
        component: Cart,
    },
    {
        path: '/product/:product_id/view',
        redirect: { name: 'view_product' },
    },
    {
        path: '/product/:product_id',
        props: true,
        name: 'view_product',
        component: ViewProduct,
    },
    {
        path: '*',
        component: {
            template: '<h1>Page not found</h1>',
        },
    },
];
```

And as you can see my route or path `/cart` has an alias `/shopping-cart`.

Below are my router links as defined in `App.vue` with `bootstrap@3` styles applied

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <router-link 
        :to="{ 
            name: 'index' 
        }" 
        tag="li" 
        active-class="active" 
        exact>
        <a>Products</a>
    </router-link>
    <router-link 
        :to="{ 
            name: 'cart', 
        }" 
        tag="li" 
        active-class="active" 
        exact>
        <a>Cart</a>
    </router-link>
</ul>
```

When I navigate to `/cart` you can see that the active class is applied as in the screenshot below
[image]

but when I navigate to the alias `/shopping-cart` you can see below that the active class is not applied
[image]

What can be done so that when I navigate to the alias the active class for the link is also applied?

I have tried to change this

```
<router-link 
    :to="{ 
        name: 'cart', 
    }" 
    tag="li" 
    active-class="active" 
    exact>
    <a>Cart</a>
</router-link>
```

to this

```
<router-link 
    :to="{ 
        name: 'cart',
        alias: 'shopping-cart',
    }" 
    tag="li" 
    active-class="active" 
    exact>
    <a>Cart</a>
</router-link>
```

but to no avail.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue on this is still open in github. Reference: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/419
you'll just have to rename your path to `/shopping-cart` and get rid of alias if you want `active-class` to be applied.

Comment: thank you for the tip but I guess we will have to wait till the issue is resolved.